# SQL on IBM i - Selecting data based on combined fields from DB

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

We are trying to select records from a file containing sales data where the date in the IBM i file is stored in 3 separate numeric fields (Year, Month, Day). We have a .net application that is using date pickers to select a from and through date range. Is there a way in an SQL statement to combine the 3 fields from the database into a single value so that the database date can be used to make the SQL select easier?

Comment: Standard sql would allow something like this: `where (year, month, day) between (2015,10,20) and (2015,10,30)`, maybe DB2 supports this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the digits command to tie them together. Your parameters will be YYYYMMDD.

```
Where digits(year) || digits(month) || digits(day)  BETWEEN ? and ?
```

Comment: Note that doing so will not perform very well, as the transformation will force the DBMS to use a full table (index) scan.  If you are on a supported release of the OS, then look at creating a [derived index](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzajq/rzajqderivedindex.htm?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks Bill - that worked! I knew there was a way to do this, but couldn't find it easily in the SQL reference manual...

Comment: Thanks Charles, I will look into that